# Issue in Converting monthly data to quarterly in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, arima

I'm working with monthly data. Have to forecast drug sales.
Also, the data points are less in count.

```
library("readxl")
library(dplyr)
library(doBy)
library("TTR")
library(forecast)
ts_dr1
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2016              0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2017    0    0    0    0 4341 3993 3495 2478  337 

>dput(ts_dr1)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4417, 4135, 
    3118, 2415, 500), .Tsp = c(2016.16666666667, 2017.66666666667, 
    12), class = "ts")
```

However, when i try to convert monthly data into quarter (as none of the functions is working with less than 2 periods),it doesn't yield expected results.

```
> quarterly <- aggregate(ts_dr1 , nfrequency=4, mean)
> quarterly 
Time Series:
Start = 2016.16666666667 
End = 2017.41666666667 
Frequency = 4 
[1]    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 1472.333 3222.667
```

Problem area:
1) It shows 1 observation ,whereas ideally, it should be 2 .
2) Also,no function is working with these(auto.arima or decompose,etc.):"as the periods are less than 2". Any workaround !
Although, my ultimate aim is to use ARIMAX on it . I'm starting with the univariate(Arima) as this is my 1st project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126). You should edit the output of `dput(ts_dr1)` to your Q so that we can help you with your specific problem. Furthermore, include all used `library()`s

Comment: Though, I think `[1]    0.3333333    0.3333333    0.0000000    2.3333333 1448.3333333 3322.0000000` does not only *show[] 1 observation* but the mean of 6 quarters.

Comment: @loki : libraries added to the code. I'm not sure ,if I correctly understand "edit the output of dput(ts_dr1) "

Comment: also,can i forecast using these 6 values. Would it be reliable, specifically , when the data is skewed(from 2017 April shift to May)

Comment: just enter `dput(ts_dr1)` into the console and paste the `structure(.....)` that is returned into your Q